# Convert DECIMAL hours to Hours:Minutes SQL SELECT (without Functions and Declare)

Tags: sql, select, db2, decimal, date-formatting

I have decimal field with for example value 0.17 (it is 0 hours and 10 minutes not 17 because 17*60/100=10,2 minutes)
I would like to convert to solely to hours and minutes in this format: **0:10**

I tried select with `SUBSTR` but I am loosing 0 value in that case.
I would like only pure SELECT without declare and functions!!! Please I cannot use those!

I saw some examples also with `TO_DATE` functions but this is not what I need because it just converts but without calculation.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: `cast(col as int)` or `trunc(col)` to get the hours and `mod(col,1) * 60/100` to get the minutes.

Comment: can you please provide full answer?

Comment: I am getting as result for minutes 0 which is not correct!

Comment: I don't know how DB2 handles modulo, maybe there's another function to get the fractional part. `col - trunc(col)` should work, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being hours, I prefer `00:10`.  You can do this using `LPAD()`:

```
concat(concat(lpad( floor( (value - floor(value))*60), 2, '0'), ':'),
       lpad(mod(floor(value), 2, '0'))
      )
```

Of course, you can just pad to one character for the hours, if you only want one "0".